# Check if private #field exists in JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, class

Is there a way to check if a private field exists in a JavaScript class? For example, how can I verify `#privateField` exists in `MyClass`?

```
class MyClass {
   #privateField = 2;
}
```

I've tried:

```
MyClass.prototype.hasOwnProperty('#privateField')   // false
```

and:

```
x = new MyClass();
x.hasOwnProperty("#privateField")   // false
```

Of course, I wouldn't expect `hasOwnProperty()` to work as a private field is not a property.

Comment: It's private so it shouldn't be accessible to anything outside of the class, but there might be a way idk

Comment: this might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_With_Private_Class_Features#checking_if_a_private_fieldmethod_exists

Comment: You can do `MyClass.toString()` as long as it's not overridden to get the implementation, then parse the JavaScript code there to search for `"#privateField"` not inside of a comment or string

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Private fields are not supposed to be visible at all outside the class definition. What will you do with the information, since you still can't access the field.

Comment: @Samathingamajig parsing the toString() result is an interesting idea but also a little tricky.

Comment: @Barmar I'd like to write a unit test to verify a student's class is written correctly.

Comment: @tronman if you're testing a student's code, then you should have access to the code itself as a string so you wouldn't have the issues of overridden `.toString()`. It'd be a bit difficult but definitely doable